# How to: Dynamic 7 day forecast calendar loops - PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm in trouble making a complex dynamic forecast calendar with a visible portion of 7 days only, with a MySQL table.

The table structure is:

#### Table: tidal_prediction

```
+----+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
| id | port_id | da_year | da_month | da_date | da_time | da_height | moon_phase |
+----+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |       1 |    2013 |  January |      04 |  16:57  |    3.75   |     0      |
|  2 |       1 |    2013 |  January |      04 |  10:57  |    2.36   |    New     |
|  3 |       1 |    2013 |  January |      04 |  08:57  |    3.35   |   Full     |
|                                   ......                                       |
+----+---------+---------+----------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

*you know it's a table with dummy data* :)

---

#### LOOK OF THE 7 DAY FORECAST CALENDAR

I made the table and CSS for the calendar of the 7 day forecast like:
[image: 7 day forecast calendar]

The Basic HTML structure of the calendar is:

```
<h4 class="tidal-year">2012</h4>
<h5 class="tidal-month">December</h5>
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr><th></th></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr><td></td></tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

NOW,
I'm struggling with the PHP loop to echo the MySQL data into the table dynamically.

### SCENARIO

The scenario is: Code will fetch "today" and echo the forecast and will also show the next 6 days forecast using the table data. Each time the loop ends to a month's end, the code will end the table too. And a new `<h5 class="tidal-month"><?php echo $next_month_name; ?></h5>` will generate with a new `<table>` following. And when the ending month denotes a year-end, then:

```
<h4 class="tidal-year"><?php echo $next_year; ?></h4>
    <h5 class="tidal-month"><?php echo $next_month_name; ?></h5>
    <table>
    ...
```

will make the new year's table.

#### SQL QUERY

```
SELECT da_year,da_month,da_date,da_time,da_height,moon_phase
FROM tidal_prediction
WHERE port_id='1'
GROUP BY port_id,da_year,da_month,da_date
ORDER BY da_year,da_month,da_date,da_time ASC
```

I'm confused with the query too. Do I need a multidimensional array? How can I make one from this table? Is my grouping correct?

And obviously, how can I make the complex PHP loop within a loop?

The question may look like a complete dependency, but I'm really trying hard googling all the aspects and possible codes (like PHP yearly calendars, multidimentional array etc.) - and finally I'm undone. :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need multidimensional arrays. Why not fetch the result row by row, maintain a variable $last_day["year"], ["month"], ["day"] so that you can compare current record against previous and see whether day, month or year changed and then output the appropriate html for that case...

Oh, btw, I would add a WHERE-Clause to the SQL to limit the result to exactly the 7days you are interested in - much more effificient than filtering in PHP afterwards...

Comment: Thanks. May be you are right. I'm trying this without a multidimentional array. Just need to share a thought: by any means I can see at least 4 individual query doing this: Q1 - Year; Q2 - Month where Year == Q1[Year]; Q3 - Date where Month == Q2[date], and Q4 - Data where Date == Q3[date]. Am I on the right way?

Comment: Not neccessarily with 4 successive querys. Rather:  If (date==last_day["day"]) {..add same day-data.} elseif (month != $last_day["month"]) {...handle change of month...} elseif (year $last_day["year"]) {...handle change of year}

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer with some real data? I'm really struggling. :(

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tidal_prediction WHERE port_id='1' AND da_year = '2013' AND da_date BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) ORDER BY da_year,da_month,da_date,da_time ASC` is showing blank page.

Comment: Yes,right. And you may like to replace the year with `YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);` so that it'll also work nxt year. :)